# from range -5 - +5 to range 0-5

Tags: voltage, series

I know there is already a lot of questions about this but I just need a quick confirmation before I solder this on my device.

I use the three resistor setup to change the range. However since it's a mapping of maximum +/-5 to maximum +5 I only need two resistors.

signal -5to5 ---2k2---2k2--- +5V ref

The new range from 0 to 5V will be measured between the series resistors.

Correct?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.

[image]

```
 Version 4
SHEET 1 2680 692
WIRE -1248 -2240 -1552 -2240
WIRE -1248 -2192 -1248 -2240
WIRE -1248 -2064 -1248 -2112
WIRE -1168 -2064 -1248 -2064
WIRE -1248 -2032 -1248 -2064
WIRE -1552 -1920 -1552 -2240
WIRE -1248 -1920 -1248 -1952
WIRE -1552 -1808 -1552 -1840
WIRE -1248 -1808 -1248 -1840
WIRE -1248 -1808 -1552 -1808
WIRE -1552 -1744 -1552 -1808
FLAG -1552 -1744 0
FLAG -1168 -2064 OUT
SYMBOL res -1264 -2208 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 2k
SYMBOL res -1264 -2048 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 2k
SYMBOL voltage -1552 -1936 R0
WINDOW 3 24 96 Invisible 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value PULSE(-5 +5 0 1)
SYMBOL voltage -1248 -1936 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 5
TEXT -1528 -1768 Left 2 !.tran 2 uic
```

Comment: Should V2 not be the other way around?

Comment: @Thor: No; V1 goes from -5 to +5 volts and V2 stays at a steady 5 volts.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I forgot to include the the voltage source in the measurement.

Answer (score 1):

With -5 volts on the input, the output must be 0 volts. With +5 volts inputted the output must be +5 volts and there's nothing non-linear in between those two limits to upset things.

Answer (score 1):

[image: With op-amp]
This circuit is summing amplifier which is adding 5V offset. The problem is that signal is inverted, so i've added follower and second inverting amplifier to invert invertion. The problem is output here is from 0V to 10V. If you want to make a range from 0V to 5V you should increase resistor value in feedback circuit in last amplifier (second from right) from 1k to 2k.